# PHP mail() changing some characters to htmlentities?

Tags: php, email, html-email, html-entities, html-encode

My PHP mail() script changes the `!` exclamation mark on some email clients such as hotmail to `%21` when the `!` is in a  tag in the email body.

Here's my script

```
$to = "myemail@outlook.com";
$subject = "Password Reset";
$body = "<a href=\"http://example.com/#!/page\">Link 1</a>
        <br><br>
        Without href: http://example.com/#!/page - regular text
    ";
$headers = "From: no-reply@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: no-reply@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP5\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

So in the script above, the `!` is changed to `%21` only when it's a link, the regular text keeps it as `/#!/`instead of transforming it to `/#%21/`

How would I go about fixing this issue so it doesn't change to `%21`?

Answer (score 0):

Some characters are encoded because they are not valid URLs. In your case [URL code points](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points) are replaced with percent-encoded byte `%`.

Comment: What would I do to fix the issue then?

Comment: It is not an issue. It's just escaped.

Comment: Ok so how do I make it not escape? I need the href to have `#!` not `#%21`?

Comment: It depends how you are reading it out. If you parse the dom you don't need to do anything special. But you can urldecode that text to convert it back. Just be aware that urls in attributes need to be encoded properly to be correct html. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php